# why big sized images.show at low resolution in webview?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, webview

Example: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/up_goer_five.png

Opening that xkcd comic will show it in such a lower resolution on my nexus one that i can't even read the text.

[image]

Edit: This happens regardless of any network agent messing up with my data. I tested via Wifi, serving a big image in my own webserver in my own local area network.

Also, happens on every browser, hence why i think it is a webview issue. Tested on Stock and Dolphin.

I notice this issue since the earlier 2.3 official roms, even though now i'm usig cyanogen nightly.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is there a setting which compresses and lowers image before downloading for lower data usage?

Comment: Forgot to mention, this happens on wifi too. Even downloading images from a server in my local LAN. And happens with both stock browser and dolphin.